# Java: what the return does here?

Tags: java, sorting, queue, comparator

I founded this code on the [web](http://www.algorithmbase.com/258/java-priority-queue-example/) . Excuse-me if a ask here,but I haven't only understand one thing. What does exactly ***return population2 - population1;***?
It sorts the items by comparing every time each other (**o1** and **o2**) , by taking the part after the colon without any eventual spaces (leadings and finals) , so the numbers, and sorting them by...?

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  PriorityQueue<String> queue = new PriorityQueue<String>(11,
  new Comparator<String>() {
   public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
   int population1 = Integer.parseInt(o1.split(":")[1].trim());
   int population2 = Integer.parseInt(o2.split(":")[1].trim());
   return population2 - population1;
   }
  });
queue.add("United States: 307006550");
queue.add("Brazil: 193733800");
queue.offer("Russia: 141850000");
queue.offer("India: 1155347700");
queue.offer("China: 1331460000");
System.out.println("Countries in database: " + queue.size());
while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println(queue.poll());
}
System.out.println("Countries in database: " + queue.size());
 }
}
```

If i try to change, for example the code to:

```
return population1 - population2;
```

it orders the numbers as:

```
United States: 307006550
Russia: 141850000
Brazil: 193733800
India: 1155347700
China: 1331460000
```

Why?

Comment: kurtzbot: excuse-me, now i've modified my last questions.

Comment: For all: i know that compare(arg1,arg2) or arg1.compareTo(arg2) returns a negative number if arg1<arg2,positive if arg1>arg2, else returns 0.  But i would to say what's the algorithm that there's behind all this. That is,after that i inserted the first it does nothing. But from the second onwards, what exact operations it does? I hope my question is clear.

Comment: I updated my answer after seeing the latest comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way comparisons are done is by comparing one value against another.  However, because comparisons result in three possible answers instead of two, we need a convenient way to let the sorter know if the first element is less than, equal to, or greater than the second element.  The easiest way to do this is to say that if element one is less than element two, return a negative number, if they are equal return a 0, and if the first element is greater, then return a positive number.

We can write this manually in code as

```
if(population1 < population2)
    return -1;
else if(population1 > population2)
    return 1;
return 0;
```

However, the sorter is only checking for negative and positive values, so the magnitude of the result does not matter, so long as a negative number means less than and a positive number means greater than.  Now, because the two values we are comparing are numbers, and we want to sort them in descending order, we can just do `population1 - popultaion2`. This will return a negative value if population1 is less than population2, 0 if they are the same, and a positive value if population1 is greater than population2.  It is simply a convenience.  If you want to opposite effect (sorting in ascending order), simply reverse the statement (as you have already shown).

In regards to sleax's latest comment, Java uses a modified [Merge Sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) that uses the information returned from the `compareTo(..)` function.  You can read about how Merge Sort works at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_Sort).

Answer (score 2):

Documentation for Comparator.compare says `Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.`

So they use the subtraction to determine if the first number is greater, equal, or less than the second, and the value sticks to the compare contract.  i.e. if first is 5 and second is 10 then 10-5=-5.  The negative return value indicates that the first argument is less than the second.

Notice when you reverse it (I'm assuming you meant that you were changing to `return population1 - population2;` rather than what you wrote, which is the same as the code sample), your population sorting is also reversed.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) of `Comparator`.

In a nutshell `Comparator` `compare(T o1,T o2)` method should return negative `Integer` when first object is greater then second, zero if they are equal, and positive value if second is greater then first.

So `return population2 - population1;` just indicates which object is greater.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you look up the documentation on the PriorityQueue class. the second argument is recieving a "Comparator" class with a method compare that will return 0 if o1 == 02, < 0 if o1 > o2, and > 0 if o1 < 02 (pretty common idiom) this method is then called form within the PriorityQueue to as part of a sort algorithm.

Comment: excuse-me for bad question! If moderators can delete the post,delete it!

Comment: I think some people are down-voting it because they didn't see effort on your part to research what a Comparator does, as this is a well documented tool. I don't know if the down votes are fair, but I believe that is their reasoning.